# could not find implicit value for parameter sqlContext compile error with Frameless and Spark 2.1

Tags: apache-spark

Trying to test out frameless 0.7.0 with spark 2.1 but when I run this:

```
  implicit val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext // required for frameless
  val artistsTDS: TypedDataset[Artist] = TypedDataset.create(defaultArtists)
```

I get the following compile error:
`could not find implicit value for parameter sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession`

Also the below doesn't print my dataset and thanks to user6910411 adding `implicit val sqlContext: SparkSession = spark` solves my original encoder error but now I get the following.

[image]

If I try frameless 0.4.0 then It seems to compile but I get the following at runtime:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.objects...
```

Comment: `SQLContext != SparkSession` (`implicit val sqlContext: SparkSession = spark`)

Comment: sorry but what exactly is the recommendation? I'm not familiar with this kind of construct. What exactly is happening in this line? Thank you.

Comment: Your code expects `implicit` `SparkSession`. You provided `implicit` `SQLContext` try `implicit val sqlContext: SparkSession = spark;`

Comment: thank you. that seems to solve the compile error but still unable to show the TypedDS I create here. I've updated my question with the example I'm trying.